# Plotting a Dataframe,pandas python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I have been working on a example in python for data analysis, the example is of baby names. I generate a data frame in the following format,
year  sex

```
1880  F       [38]     M       [14] 
1881  F       [38]     M       [14] 
1882  F       [38]     M       [15] 
1883  F       [39]     M       [15] 
1884  F       [39]     M       [16]
```

I have generated this using the following routine, which returns an index value.

```
def get_quantile_count(group, q=0.5):
    group = group.sort_index(by='prop', ascending=False)
    return group.prop.cumsum().searchsorted(q) + 1
```

When I try to plot this dataframe I am getting an error.Are these indices not being recognized as numerical values?

```
TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem this is demonstration of solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from sklearn import preprocessing


train = pd.DataFrame([['F','1885'],['F','1884'],['F','1882'],['M','1881'],['NA','1882']],columns = ['sex','db'])

#converting F/M/NA to integers
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(train['sex'])
train['sex'] = le.transform(train['sex'])
train = train.astype(float)

plt.plot(train['sex'],train['db'],color='green', linestyle='dashed', marker='o',
        markerfacecolor='blue', markersize=12)
plt.show()
```

Comment: if you create Figure and Axes objects, you should plot against the Axes directly (i.e., `ax.plot(tra...)`)